# How to fold markdown using the built-in markdown mode?

Tags: folding, filetype-markdown

Looking at the [ftplugin file for markdown](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/89bcfda6834aba724d12554a34b9ed49f5789fd5/runtime/ftplugin/markdown.vim) in Vim, it certainly appears that folding is supported, but I cannot get folding to work.

If I have some content like this:

```
# A heading

Some content.
More content.
```

How do I fold up this heading and its content?

Answer (score 8):

### Markdown folding:

As ana found out, for markdown specifically make sure that you have `let g:markdown_folding = 1` or folding wont be "turned on".

### General folding tips:

Vim won't fold automatically, try putting your cursor over the text and doing `zc`. This should close the fold.

If you want some visual context even when it's not folded try the foldcolumn option!

```
set foldcolumn=2
```

For more info see `:h zo` and `:h foldcolumn`

Comment: @Tumbler41  No. It is not working for me. I tried `let g:markdown_folding=1` and zM zR zo zc. Nothing works. Running Neovim 0.1.7.

Comment: This answer is true for Vim. I've never used Neovim and have no idea of the differences or idiosyncrasies of it.

Comment: @Tumbler41 OK. But it does not work on vim 8 also. I have `let g:markdown_folding=1`, `ft=markdown` and `foldmethod=syntax`. What am I missing?

Comment: Yea.. didnt work for vim8 either

Comment: yeah, for me neither. I can't make it work :(

Answer (score 3):

I enable folding in markdown files by using the following in my .vimrc:

```
set foldmethod = manual
set foldcolumn = 1
highlight Folded ctermbg = NONE
highlight FoldColumn ctermbg = NONE
let g:markdown_folding = 1
let g:markdown_enable_folding = 1
```

Yet, folding was failing with the message "no folding found" until I removed the `vimwiki` plugin.

Comment: `E474: Invalid argument: foldmethod =`
`E521: Number required after =: foldcolumn =`

Comment: This answer works great. No plugins needed and just a small snippet added to your .vimrc file. The tip about removing the vimwiki plugin was the missing piece. Thank you sir!