# Enable Expr Folding in Markdown

Tags: folding, filetype-markdown

I want to fold in markdown using [the built in markdown plugin](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/89bcfda6834aba724d12554a34b9ed49f5789fd5/runtime/ftplugin/markdown.vim) that I believe should come with the version of vim I have (`Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Apr 23 2019 20:02:08)`).

I am struggling to make the answers in [the other question on this topic](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9543/how-to-fold-markdown-using-the-built-in-markdown-mode) work for me.

I have no plugins installed, and I made my `.vimrc` the most minimal it can be:

```
let g:markdown_folding = 1
let g:markdown_fenced_languages = ['vim', 'yaml', 'python', 'bash=sh', 'sql', 'git', 'make', 'html', 'css', 'javascript', 'js=javascript', 'json=javascript', 'xml']
syntax enable
set nocompatible
```

With this, if I open a markdown file, I see that it is highlighted correctly, and `:set ft?` returns `markdown`. However, `:set foldmethod?` always returns `manual`, and `zc` returns `E490: fold not found`.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, and I've run out of things to try. The only thing I can think of is that `if has("folding")` from that built in plugin must be returning false, but I don't know what that syntax is or how to enable folding.

Comment: If you execute the command `:filetype`... Do you see `filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON`? If you see `plugin:OFF`, then that might explain what you're seeing... Happy to turn this into an answer, if it turns out this is the cause of your issue... Cheers!

Comment: You can also use the `:scriptnames` command to confirm/check that the `ftplugin/markdown.vim` script is being sourced. Please use the commands suggested and please *edit* the question to include your findings. (Ok to add a comment indicating you've done that, feel free to mention @filbranden and I'll get a notification about it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: You should include the command `filetype plugin on` in your vimrc. You most probably want `filetype plugin indent on` to enable all filetype-related types of plugins.

Vim has a handful of filetype-related features, and they can be enabled and disabled individually using the `:filetype` command. (Technically, syntax highlighting is also dependent on filetypes, but you use the `:syntax` command to enable or disable it.)

The `:filetype` command can be used to enable filetype detection, which is a pre-requisite for all the other features (since the other features depend on knowing *which* filetype to load plugins for.) Detection is enabled with `filetype on`.

Then there are the `indent` plugins (enabled with `filetype indent on`), which typically set `'indentexpr'` to set up rules for automatic indentation for that particular filetype.

And finally there's the `plugin` part, which enables loading Vim files from the `ftplugin/` directory, such as the one `markdown.vim` you identified.

You can check whether filetype features are enabled with:

```
:filetype
```

If you see `filetype detection:OFF  plugin:OFF  indent:OFF`, that means it's disabled. (If you see `detection:ON` but another feature is `OFF`, it's not fully enabled either.)

To fix that and enable all filetype features use:

```
:filetype plugin indent on
```

If you want that to be always the case, include that line in your vimrc.